# Finding all possible remainders of perfect squares mod $n$, $n\in \mathbb{Z_+}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

Is there a way to generalize what remainders of perfect squares to expect for different bases.  for $a^2\equiv 0,1 \text{ mod } 3$.  but what about $a^2\equiv r \text{ mod } n \in \mathbb{Z_+}$.  For e.g if I want to know all the possible remainders $r$ for $a^2$ mod $117$, then will it still have $0,1$, if not, then how can I find all the remainders?

**Edit**
Well clearly for the e.g I provided we'd have all $a^2\leq 117$ in $r$, but I guess the question was whether or not the $r$ that appear in base $5$ will also appear in base $22$, and the $r$ in base $q$ will also appear in base $k$, s.t $q<k$

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_residue

Comment: For $n$ prime, it is always half of the non-zero remainders, and you can use quadratic reciprocity to check any particular $r$.

Comment: $0$ and $1$ will always be residues of perfect squares to any modulus, but there will generally be others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there's some machinery you can use to figure out if $r$ is a remainder of a perfect square mod $n$.  These $r$'s are called quadratic residues, and the main technique at play to see if $r$ is a quadratic residue is [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) and properties of Legendre symbols.